# MySQL Workbench Bug, crashes when I store password or connect

Tags: windows-7, mysql-workbench

I'm having issues with MySQL Workbench. I go into `Manage Connections...` and when I either click on `Password: Store in Vault` or I try to connect without a password I get this error:

`Unhandled NET framework connection [4112]`

When I debug it on VB it returns:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mforms.wr.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

I am on a Windows 7 Pro PC, 64-bit.

You can see the bug report I sent to Oracle which is a duplicate of similar bugs and crashes at this [link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80930).

Thank you for your assistance.

Also I felt that this was a good question for Superuser but if anyone feels it would be better dealt with on DBA or another SE site please feel free to suggest a migration.